# How to edit yaml file in Dockerfile or in shell?

Tags: docker, yaml

In Dockerfile, I upload one configuration file from curl, which I then need to edit a little, here is an example structure:

```
client:
  ...
server:
  applicationConnectors:
  - type: http
    port: 8989
    # for security reasons bind to localhost
    bindHost: localhost
  requestLog:
      appenders: []
  adminConnectors:
  - type: http
    port: 8990
    bindHost: localhost
```

I need to edit both `bindHost` parameters, it would be desirable if I could pass their values as a parameter during `docker build`, but I didn’t seem to find anything on the Internet or in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question right, in your Dockerfile command, pipe your curl to a sed:

```
curl XXX | sed -e "s/bindHost: localhost/bindHost: ${your_variable}/g" > yourfile.yaml
```

Or you can edit your file after it was been downloaded:

```
sed -ie "s/bindHost: localhost/bindHost: ${your_variable}/g" /path/to/your/file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass  values to your Dockerfile with '--build-arg', and use that value in a `RUN sed` call, for instance to inject an IP address parameter:

```
FROM whatever

COPY config.file /etc/config.file
ARG IPADDR
RUN sed -i -r "s/#IPADDR#/$IPADDR/g" /etc/config.file
```

And you build with:

```
docker build -t foobar --build-arg IPADDR=11.12.13.14 .
```

You can also convert the build arguments into runtime environment variables:

```
ARG ARGVAR
ENV ENVVAR $ARGVAR
```

which would be nicer if your config syntax can perform a substitution of variables from the environment (no need to run `sed`).

But this makes the image a bit too cast in concrete, you can instead set the environment variables when you start the container (`docker run` with `--env`, `--env-list`) and use these values to edit the config file on-the-fly in a script that is the container entry point, unless of course your config syntax (or start parameters) can do the envvar substitution.